# Search and replace any number separated by : trailing with number or alphabet separated by . and / or - or _

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

Search pattern examples

```
"0:4.10.5-5.el7"
"0:0.7.7-13.20120626.ov7"
"6:4.14.8-6.po7_3"
```

1. How to search and print all occurrences like above patterns where the first number can be any number ranging from 0-9 separated by ":" trailing with any number or alphabet ranging from a-z separated by . or. in vi editor ?

I could search the occurrences of all the patterns starting with any number [0-9] separated by ":" using

```
:%s/[0-9]\+\:
```

2. how to remove all the occurrences till end of line of each occurrence

Comment: This worked for removing all occurrences of any wild character trailing : till end of line :%s/[0-9]:.*//g

Comment: To replace beginning of each line in the entire file with a specific pattern ==> :%s/^/stringtoreplace/

Comment: place all pattern test cases on each line enclosed with `\`\`\``. And add what you want the result to be.

Comment: So 1) do you want to match all your examples or what you described as test? If the latter you can use `/\d:[0-9a-z\.]\+` if you want to match your examples you'll need to add `_-` to `[0-9a-z\.]`. 2) Your second question is not clear: do you want to remove everything after the `:` in this case you can use `:%s/\d\+:\zs[0-9a-z\.]\+//`. If you want to remove all the lines matching the previous pattern you can use a global command like `:g/\d\+:[0-9a-z-\.]\+/d`. Maybe try to clarify your question so that we can answer it precisely.

Comment: And  3) If what you said in your comments is what you were looking for, please write an answer with proper formatting.